# advanced custom fields: update/create image field

Tags: image, field, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following problem: I've created an image-field with *acf* for my custom post type in which I want to store several hundred images.

1. I import these images with wordpress.
2. I run an import with the "really simple csv importer" in order to create a lot of posts and assign the images that I uploaded in the 1. step to the acf image field.

I've tried a lot with the `update_field()` and the `get_field_object()` functions but nothing worked. The documentation for the `update_field()` function is unfortunately very incomplete, how do I have to use this function in order to update the image field?

This is the code I'm using:

```
function really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter( $meta, $post, $is_update ) {
  $attachment_url = $meta['field_55f2be2a39177'];
  $image_id = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $attachment_url ); // function to retrieve the image id that i need for the update_field()
  $field_key = "field_55f2be2a39177";
  update_field($field_key, $image_id);
  return $meta;
} 

add_filter( 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta', 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and where you failing

Comment: `function really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter( $meta, $post, $is_update ) {
  $attachment_url = $meta['field_55f2be2a39177'];
  $image_id = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $attachment_url ); // function to retrieve the image id that i need for the update_field()
  $field_key = "field_55f2be2a39177";
  update_field($field_key, $image_id);
  return $meta;}
add_filter( 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta', 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter', 10, 3 );`

Answer (score 0):

In this case I dont think you need to call update_field() and can instead do this.

```
function really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter( $meta, $post, $is_update ) {
  $image_id = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url( $attachment_url ); // function to retrieve the image id that i need for the update_field()
  //set the value of the ACF field to the image id.
  $meta['field_55f2be2a39177'] = $image_id;
  return $meta;
} 

add_filter( 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta', 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter', 10, 3 );
```